# Connecting to API & Parsing JSON using Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, codable

Using Swift 4, I'm trying to connect to an API for a site using a GET Method with authentication like so:

```
let theString = apiTxt.text! + ":"
let newUser = theString.toBase64()

let url = URL(string: "https://website.net/api/v1/user/")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
let authorizationKey = "Basic ".appending(newUser)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue(authorizationKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.timeoutInterval = 20000.0

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
        print(json)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}).resume()
```

I know it's working properly, because it shows up in my API calls as authenticated. My issue is actually retrieving the JSON that is generated on the page, and parsing it in Swift. It seems the way I do it some of the information isn't brought over, and then there's no way for me to get specific parts. For reference, this is what the result is like on a succesful call.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFyIm.png)

And this is what happens when json the variable is printed.

```
["message": , "result": {
    additionalgroups =     (
        0
    );
    avatar = "./uploads/avatars/avatar_2306826.png?dateline=1511031658";
    avatartype = upload;
    displaygroup = 28;
    lastactive = "2017-12-13T22:53:37Z";
    postnum = 1750;
    regdate = "2014-05-28T02:19:03Z";
    reputation = 388;
    timeonline = 5173540;
    usergroup = 28;
    username = BillyJoe;
    usertitle = "Hey";
}, "header": {
    unreadpms = 0;
}, "success": 1]
```

Which, is not right.

EDIT:

So for example, I get the error: Invalid top-level type in JSON write. This happens when I run this code:

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data) 
//let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) 
let decoder = JSONDecoder() 
let thing = try! decoder.decode(userBasicInfo.self, from: jsonData)
print(thing)
```

Using this structure:

```
struct userBasicInfo: Codable {
        let username: String
        let avatar: String
        let reputation: Int
    }
```

Comment: Why do you say your result isn't right? It's the same as the picture.

Comment: Oh wait, I just noticed it was. It wasn't the first time, but now my problem is parsing this data. I haven't found a way to properly parse it.

Comment: There are countless examples of parsing JSON data. Be specific about what your issue is. [Edit] your question with your attempt to get the desired data from `json`. Clearly explain what issues you are having.